# Backup Bookmarklet Code

Tags: backup, bookmarklet

Hi i have bookmarklet code to load a scripts from a mirrored backup location if my main hosting goes down, it works but i want to know the best way to do this as i know the current way i am doing it is probably not the best way.

(**this is a example of my backup bookmarlet code expanded**)

```js
javascript: (function () {
var scriptname = 'testscript';

function checkServerStatus() {
    var v = setTimeout(function () {
        loadscript('backupserver.hardiman.co.nz')
    }, 4500);
    var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    a.onload = function () {
        clearTimeout(v);
        loadscript('screepts.com')
    };
    a.src = 'http://screepts.com/ping.gif?' + Math.random();
}
checkServerStatus();

function loadscript(b) {
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.src = 'http://' + b + '/bm/' + scriptname + '.js?' + Math.random();
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a)
}
})();`
```

And this is it wrapped up as a bookmarklet :

```html
<a href="javascript:%28function%28%29%7Bvar c%3D'testscript'%3Bfunction checkServerStatus%28%29%7Bvar v%3DsetTimeout%28function%28%29%7Bloadscript%28'backupserver.hardiman.co.nz'%29%7D,4500%29%3Bvar a%3Ddocument.body.appendChild%28document.createElement%28'img'%29%29%3Ba.onload%3Dfunction%28%29%7BclearTimeout%28v%29%3Bloadscript%28'screepts.com'%29%7D%3Ba.src%3D'http://screepts.com/ping.gif%3F'%2BMath.random%28%29%3B%7DcheckServerStatus%28%29%3Bfunction loadscript%28b%29%7Bvar a%3Ddocument.createElement%28'script'%29%3Ba.type%3D'text/javascript'%3Ba.src%3D'http://'%2Bb%2B'/bm/'%2Bc%2B'.js%3F'%2BMath.random%28%29%3Bdocument.getElementsByTagName%28'head'%29%5B0%5D.appendChild%28a%29%7D%7D%29%28%29%3B">Test Script</a>
```

Any help or advice on loading a script from a backup server would be greatly appreciated..

---

Okay sorry i should have been more specific on the question. Since my hosting went down i was able to test the above code properly. I think the only thing i need to do is parse what server was loaded to the script.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean "Can the JavaScript of my bookmarklet be improved?" or "Is a bookmarklet the best way to achieve this?". If it's the former, then the code looks fine to me. If it's the latter I'd need to know a bit more about the intended user base.

Comment: @dumbledad i have a group of js scripts that are for Facebook games & i have just found my shared hosting is not the best. I was seeing if could improve this or if there was another better way to check if a server was down.

Comment: But who is intended to click the bookmarklet? Is it you when you are testing the game, or your users, the players? If it's you the above looks fine, but for your users I cannot see how a bookmarklet would weave into the expected game experience.